# No rotation lock icon in quick settings in Lollipop on Nexus 5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, auto-rotation, quick-settings

I've seen in several reviews that Lollipop comes with a new rotation lock icon in quick settings:

ArsTechnica:
[image: screenshot from Ars Technica]

But my phone doesn't have it:

[image: screenshot of my device]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

How can I get the rotation toggle to show up?

Comment: It would help to know which phone you do have, and if you have any custom ROM, kernel, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the solution

Goto settings-> accessibility-> enable AUTO ROTATE.... Then we have the toggle button in notification screen as well

Comment: Was turned on, but turning off and on again did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Quick settings toggles in Lollipop are populated based on when you last used a setting. As a result, once you toggle a setting through the device's settings, it will automatically populate in the quick settings and stay there as long as you use it at least once every thirty days, which is why you had to toggle it to make it appear.